# Prove that $ABC$ is equilateral?

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with incenter $I$ and let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be the incenters of the triangles $BIC$, $CIA$ and $AIB$, respectively. Let the triangle $XYZ$ be equilateral. Prove that $ABC$ is equilateral too.

This is IMO Shortlist 2009 - Problem G7,solution can see the  page 64  http://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2009SL.pdf

My question:Is there a solution without trigonometry?

[image]

Comment: Trigonometric functions are merely geometric ratios. Try proving it with trigonometric functions and then replace them with ratios (i.e. $\sin \text{angle}= \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$).

Comment: Triangle ABC has same in centre as it's centroid